# Start python by typing "py" in zsh prompt?

Tags: python, shell, alias, zsh

I'm using [zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/). I installed the latest version of Python 3 with Homebrew. I can start the Python interpreter by typing `python3` at the shell prompt.

Is there a way to create an alias or something like that to start python3 just by typing `py` ? As I said before, I installed python with Homebrew. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `alias py=python3` in `~/.zshrc`. Homebrew is irrelevant.